# Working with font-awesome 4.7 in extjs 7.3

Tags: font-awesome, extjs7

I was upgrading an app build with an old extjs framework version (v 6.7) which used the old font-awesome package up to v4.7 I guess. I upgraded the app now to the 7.3 framework version which uses the new font-awesome package. Now my question is, is there a possibility to use the old package instead? I tried just swapping out the package folders but sencha cmd then throws a fashion error like this:

```
[LOG] Fashion Error : Reference to undeclared variable : $fa_fw_width :
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR]   at net.sf.antcontrib
[ERR] .logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
```

What I tried as well was swapping the data in the ext\packages\font-awesome\resources\fonts folder, which seemed to make no difference.
and swapping out both folders (\resources and \sass) lead to this building failure:

```
[LOG] Fashion Error : Reference to undeclared variable : $fa_var_thumbtack :
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.
[ERR] ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
```